# Python HTTPServer random delays

Tags: python, http, server, delay

I have a quite simple script on windows with Python 3.8.17 running a HTTP-Server. Most requests have a delay of 2-5ms but every 3-5 requests has a delay from mostly exact 1 minute (sorry, before I wrote 1s), sometimes a little bit more but not less.

I already switched from localhost to http://127.0.0.1:90/ and that helped with a general delay but these occassionally occurring requests are still not fixed.

The server is not blocked during this time. When I reload the page, the delayed request is canceled and the next request has again 3-5ms.

Any idea to get rid of these delayed requests? I know Linux but unfortunately that is not an option. ;)

Is there a good and simple alternative to http.server that does not suffer from that issue?

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

class Srvr(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # GET-Anfragen
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path != "/favicon.ico":

            # status
            self.send_response(200)

            # header
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()

            # body
            self.wfile.write("...".encode())

def run():
    cfg = ("", 90)
    httpd = HTTPServer(cfg, Srvr)
    print("[srvr] started!")

    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```